# Plotting training and validation loss curve in my PyTorch model

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, pytorch, training-data

I developed my model using the following code.

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data.drop('cnt', axis=1).values
        self.targets = data['cnt'].values

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.targets)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x = self.data[idx]
        y = self.targets[idx]
        return x, y

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_hidden_layers):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(num_hidden_layers):
            self.hidden_layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size))
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.input_layer(x))
        for layer in self.hidden_layers:
            x = torch.relu(layer(x))
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

input_size = 57
hidden_size = 128
output_size = 1
num_hidden_layers = 2
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 100

model = MyModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_hidden_layers)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

train_dataset = MyDataset(train_data)
val_dataset = MyDataset(val_data)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    for inputs, targets in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs.float())
        loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), targets.float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
    train_loss /= len(train_loader.dataset)

    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    val_preds = []
    val_targets = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, targets in val_loader:
            outputs = model(inputs.float())
            loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), targets.float())
            val_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            val_preds += outputs.squeeze().tolist()
            val_targets += targets.tolist()
        val_loss /= len(val_loader.dataset)
        val_r2 = r2_score(val_targets, val_preds)
        val_mse = mean_squared_error(val_targets, val_preds, squared=True)

    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, '
          f'Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, '
          f'Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, '
          f'Validation R^2: {val_r2:.4f}, '
          f'Validation MSE: {val_mse:.4f}')
```

And it gives me the results showing the training loss and validation loss in each epoch.
[result of each epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVGB2.png)

Then I try to plot training and validation loss curve using the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_losses = []
val_losses = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):    
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)

plt.plot(train_losses, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(val_losses, label='Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, the training loss and validation loss curves in the plot do not align with the losses of each epoch above. Why is my plot not showing the "curves"?
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiEyZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you print `train_loss` and `val_loss` within the fitting loop and from what you posted it seems that `train_losses` and `val_losses` for plotting is filled afterwards with a constant value (probably the last value assigned in the fitting loop).

So just do

```
...
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, '
          f'Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, '
          f'Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, '
          f'Validation R^2: {val_r2:.4f}, '
          f'Validation MSE: {val_mse:.4f}')
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
```

And then plot `train_losses` and `val_losses` as before.